# How to enable experimental features from Traceur (runtime)

Tags: javascript, async-await, traceur, ecmascript-2016

I have the following setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/bin/traceur.js"></script>
    <script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/src/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

This works great, but when I try experimental features it breaks. I tried `async` - `await`

```
async makeItSo(input) {
    await timeout(1000); 
    ...
}
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

which underlines the `async` keyword.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kcob19h2/)

On the [Traceur Wiki](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures) it is stated that you should manually enable experimental features (not sure if this applies to the runtime variant).

So the question is, can experimental features be enabled for the runtime ?

Comment: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Options-for-Compiling#options-in-the-browser